# Storing JS counting numbers to continue using HTML5 web storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-storage

I'm trying to store my script that counts numbers starting from 23,000 to always continue to appear it's "live" and always counting using Web Storage. I've tried implementing this and so far, I can't seem to get it to work. What would be the best solution to get this to work and function to always count even when refreshing, etc? [I've included my JS Fiddle](http://bit.ly/1hBOcLa) and code below. Any help is kindly appreciated!!

EDIT: To clarify.. I'm trying to have a "live" counter always going no matter what when you go to the page, refresh it, whatever. It's just always going and getting bigger no matter what just like my script does.. However, everytime I refresh it starts back at 23,000.

HTML

```
<span id="liveNumbers">23,000</span>
```

JS

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
       setInterval(function(){
       random = (Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1));
       var plus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 1;
       random = random * plus; 
       currentnumber = document.getElementById('liveNumbers');
       var curnum = parseInt(currentnumber.innerHTML.replace(",",""));

       document.getElementById('liveNumbers').innerHTML = 
           commaSeparateNumber(curnum + random);
       }, 3000);

       function commaSeparateNumber(val){
       while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
          val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
       }
       return val;
     }
  }
else
  {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  }
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do. you need to store numbers in local storage or store the script?

Comment: @TilwinJoy Trying to store these numbers to continue counting, so let's say it initially started at 23,000 but I come back to the same page 12 days later and it's probably at 120,000 (just assuming).

Essentially, I'm trying to have a "live" counter always going no matter what when you go to the page, refresh it, whatever. It's just always going and getting bigger.

Comment: This isn't possible without some server-side code. Javascript executes upon requests - it isn't kept alive all the time.

Comment: You cant execute a client side script without the client. As soon as the user leaves your page, your script will stop executing. You can increment the number stored in localstorage, and then restore from that saved value.

Comment: You can't do that with javascript, even with local storage

Comment: @CollinHenderson Would any of you fella's know the right direction to achieve this effect? It's kindly appreciated. Thanks so much for your time guys.

Comment: @ryan Thanks for your reply! Any chance, how I could achieve this effect I have got going? Appreciate for your time.

Comment: You'd need some kind of cron script on your server that writes to a JSON file every x seconds/minutes/hours. You could then use AJAX to request the contents of the JSON file.

Comment: Should the counting pause while the user is not in the page or should it keep track of the time the user isn't in the page?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Counting is always going no matter what! Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: @CollinHenderson Hm, thank you! I'll try and look those up. Don't really have a clue where to start with that but sounds like a solution!

Comment: If the counting didn't involve randomness, it'd be as simple as comparing timestamps (save initial timestamp in the first load and compare subsequent page loads' timestamps to it). I guess you can still do timestamps comparison with some formula for the randomness increment.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Sounds very interesting.. Would you happen to know a solution without randomness to start from to achieve such effect? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yeah, this is overly simplistic and assumes 1 second = 1 number increment, but should be a start: http://jsfiddle.net/ub3Bn/14/

Comment: For your use case, the randomness which occurs while the user is in the page should be stored too together with the final timestamp in  a `window.onbeforeunload` handler, and the randomness that would happen when the user is not in the page would have to be applied to `Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) - lastSessionEndTime`.. It is quite more complex.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Dude, you're a genius. This first JSFiddle is working amazingly. I'm trying to achieve the effect you're doing with the randomness (of at least 1 to 3) right now, this is really helpful man.

If you happen to know or have a fiddle for that as well, it would mean the world! Make an answer, so I can check it for ya! You are so awesome for helping out. Thank you.

Comment: @DoPeT Sorry, having a bit busy day but I've submitted a more detailed solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ub3Bn/17/)

The logic:

- On first visit (no `localStorage` data) the counter is reset to `23000`.
- Counter runs while page is open.
- When closing the page, the current counter value is stored together with the current timestamp (`lastSessionEnd`).
- When user loads the page again, the time that has passed since he closed the page is translated into interval cycles which are passed to the `randomRange` function and added to the stored counter from the last session.

Here's the code:

```
if(window.localStorage) {
    //configs
    var updateInterval = 3000; //ms
    function randomRange() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1; // [1..3] range
    }


    var counter = +localStorage.getItem('counter');
    if (!counter) { //first load
        counter = 23000;
    } else { //simulate randomness that would have happened while the user was away from the page
        var lastSessionEnd = +localStorage.getItem('lastSessionEnd');
        for(var l = Math.floor((getUnixTimeStamp() - lastSessionEnd)*1000/updateInterval); l--;) {
            counter += randomRange();
        }
    }

    var liveNumbers = document.getElementById('liveNumbers'); //cache DOM query
    function refreshDisplay() {
        liveNumbers.innerHTML = commaSeparateNumber(counter);
    }
    refreshDisplay();
    setInterval(function() {
        counter += randomRange();
        refreshDisplay();
    }, updateInterval);

    function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
        while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
            val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        }
        return val;
    }

    function getUnixTimeStamp() {
        return Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
        localStorage.setItem('lastSessionEnd', getUnixTimeStamp());
    });
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

**NOTE:** this is not perfect, here are the caveats:

- As it is done purely in the front-end, it is easily hackable by manipulating the `localStorage`. Don't use this for important stuff.
- As it uses the `localStorage` API, if the user opens the page in more than one browser (or more than one computer/device), each one will have a different counter. Also, cleaning all personal data will reset the counter.
- Finally, there's an interval cycle rounding error, it doesn't account for interrupted interval cycles. E.g. the user closes the page midway through an interval cycle, the next time he opens the page that half-cycle will be discarded and a new one starts. I believe this is a small detail which would take more effort to fix than it's worth, but I'll leave that decision and effort to you.

Comment: I couldn't ask for a better answer and thank you enough for your time. Thanks again.